# not show to value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am creating a project like `eCommerce site calculator`

like below,

if i click on `+` then add `one` in input field and multiple by the price and show as actual price

and show price sub total with vat total like below

but i didn't got  any solution in the google search please help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$(".button-click a").on("click", function() {

  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev().val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) +1;
      
      
      var price = $button.parents('ul').next('.price').find('.js-applePrice').text();
      var totalAdd = newVal* parseInt(price);
       alert(totalAdd) ;   

    } else {
   // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }
  $button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal); 

});

 });
```

```css
.some-div{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    border:solid 1px green;
    margin:2px;
}
.some-div> *, .some-div > ul li{
    float:left;
}
.some-div > ul, .some-div > ul li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.some-div > ul > li a{
    display:block; text-decoration:none;color:#fff; padding:5px; font-size:15px; background:#000;margin-right:5px;
}
.price{padding:0 10px;border:solid 1px green;font-weight:bold;}

.totalprice{
    padding:0 10px;border:solid 1px green;font-weight:bold; color:red;margin-left:10px;
}
.remove{
    float:right;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-div">

    
        <label for="">Apple:</label>
         <input type="text" name="a" maxlength="100" value="0" />
   
    <ul class="button-click">
      <li><a href="#">+</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
     </ul>
    <span class="price">Price:<i class="js-applePrice">25.41</i></span>
    <span class="totalprice">Total Rs. <i class="js-total">250</i></span>
    
    <a href="#" class="remove">*</a>
</div>
<div class="some-div">
    
        <label for="">Orange:</label>
         <input type="text" name="b" maxlength="100" value="0" />
   
    <ul class="button-click">
      <li><a href="#">+</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
     </ul>
    <span class="price">Price:<i class="js-applePrice">12.00</i></span>
    <span class="totalprice">Total Rs. <i class="js-total">150</i></span>
    
    <a href="#" class="remove">*</a>
</div>

<div class="some-div">

    
        <label for="">Sampu:</label>
         <input type="text" name="c" maxlength="100" value="0" />
   
    <ul class="button-click">
      <li><a href="#">+</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
     </ul>
    <span class="price">Price:<i class="js-applePrice">15</i></span>
    <span class="totalprice">Total Rs. <i class="js-total">250</i></span>
    
    <a href="#" class="remove">*</a>
</div>

<!-- ---------------- -->

<div class="totalPrice">
        <div class="">Sub Total :- <span class="js-Sub-total"></span></div>
    <div class="">Vat :- 22%</div>
    <div class="">Total :- <span class="js-total"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What was the issue here? DO you want to update the price?

Comment: Yes i want to update price if i click to + icon or - icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added some logic to make it a complete example.

I've made this change in HTML to make the VAT to be configurable.

```
<div class="">Vat :- <span class="vat">22</span>%</div>
```

Few things which i noticed in your code are:

You're redefining variables in multiple places in the same function. Better practice would be declare all variables at top of the function and assign values as required. No need to use `var` keyword everywhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".button-click a").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev().val();
    var newVal, price,totalAdd ;
    price = $button.parents('ul').next('.price').find('.js-applePrice').text();
    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 0) {
            newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }
    totalAdd = newVal * parseFloat(price);
    $(this).closest("ul").siblings(".totalprice").find(".js-total").text(totalAdd);
    
    $button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);
    var tol = 0;
    $("span i.js-total").each(function (index, value) {
        tol += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $("div.totalPrice").find("div .js-Sub-total").text(tol);
    var vat = parseFloat($(".vat").text());
    var vatCalc = parseFloat(tol * vat) / 100;
    $("div.totalPrice").find("div .js-total").text((tol + vatCalc).toFixed(2));
});
});
```

```css
.some-div{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    border:solid 1px green;
    margin:2px;
}
.some-div> *, .some-div > ul li{
    float:left;
}
.some-div > ul, .some-div > ul li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.some-div > ul > li a{
    display:block; text-decoration:none;color:#fff; padding:5px; font-size:15px; background:#000;margin-right:5px;
}
.price{padding:0 10px;border:solid 1px green;font-weight:bold;}

.totalprice{
    padding:0 10px;border:solid 1px green;font-weight:bold; color:red;margin-left:10px;
}
.remove{
    float:right;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-div">

    
        <label for="">Apple:</label>
         <input type="text" name="a" maxlength="100" value="0" />
   
    <ul class="button-click">
      <li><a href="#">+</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
     </ul>
    <span class="price">Price:<i class="js-applePrice">25.41</i></span>
    <span class="totalprice">Total Rs. <i class="js-total">0</i></span>
    
    <a href="#" class="remove">*</a>
</div>


<div class="some-div">

    
        <label for="">Orange:</label>
         <input type="text" name="b" maxlength="100" value="0" />
   
    <ul class="button-click">
      <li><a href="#">+</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
     </ul>
    <span class="price">Price:<i class="js-applePrice">12.00</i></span>
    <span class="totalprice">Total Rs. <i class="js-total">0</i></span>
    
    <a href="#" class="remove">*</a>
</div>



<div class="some-div">

    
        <label for="">Sampu:</label>
         <input type="text" name="c" maxlength="100" value="0" />
   
    <ul class="button-click">
      <li><a href="#">+</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
     </ul>
    <span class="price">Price:<i class="js-applePrice">15</i></span>
    <span class="totalprice">Total Rs. <i class="js-total">0</i></span>
    
    <a href="#" class="remove">*</a>
</div>

<!-- ---------------- -->

<div class="totalPrice">
        <div class="">Sub Total :- <span class="js-Sub-total"></span></div>
    <div class="">Vat :- <span class="vat">22</span>%</div>
    <div class="">Total :- <span class="js-total"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I wrote some time ago. So you add and subtract buttons will both have a class called `js-qty-adjuster`, and an additional `js-add` class on the addition button.

```
     function updatePrice(qty){
       var priceOfSingleItem = //get the price of a single item here,
           newPrice = priceOfSingleItem * qty;

       $.ajax({

        url: 'basket.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: newPrice//the update price,
        success: function(result){
             $('#total-price').html( newPrice )
         }
        });
     }

     $('.js-qty-adjuster').on('click', function() {
        var el = $(this),
            id = el.data('id'),
            qtySelector = el.siblings('.js-quantity'),
            qty = parseInt( qtySelector.val() );

        // Add or subtract from the current quantity
        if (el.hasClass('js-add')) {
          qty = qty + 1;
        } else {
          qty = qty - 1;
          if (qty <= 1) {
            qty = 1;
          }
        }

        // Update the input's number
        qtySelector.val(qty);
        updatePrice(qty);

      });
```

html for quantity adjuster:

```
<div id="quantity-wrapper" class="quantity-selector-wrapper left">
    <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector text-center js-quantity">
    <a class="downer js-qty-adjuster qty-adjuster text-center js-add add" data-property="add" field="quantity">+</a>
    <a class="up js-qty-adjuster qty-adjuster  text-center js-minus minus" data-property="minus" field="quantity">-</a>
 </div>
```

Once you change the quantity, you could simply fetch the price of a single item(using ajax or output the value in the template as a data-attribute that you can access) and multiply the values in the same function. Use Ajax to do a post request of the updated value and if the request is a success, update your html as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of alerting, set the value back to the DOM.
And for computing monetary unit use **parseFloat** instead.

```
var price = $button.parents('ul').next('.price').find('.js-applePrice').text();
var totalAdd = newVal * parseFloat(price); ;
$button.parents('ul').next('.price').find('.js-applePrice').text(totalAdd);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code `var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev()` refers to div. You need to get the  input's value in that div. Use `$button.closest("ul").prev().find("input")`

```
$(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var inputText = $button.closest("ul").prev().find("input");
    var oldValue = inputText.val();
    var newVal;
    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        if (newVal == -1)
            newVal = 0;
    }
    inputText.val(newVal)
    var price = $button.parents('ul').next('.price').find('.js-applePrice').text();
    var totalAdd = newVal * parseFloat(price);
    $button.closest(".some-div").find(".totalprice .js-total").text(totalAdd);

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/46/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, updating total price for each item :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$(".button-click a").on("click", function() {

  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev().val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) +1;


      var price = $button.parents('ul').next('.price').find("i").text();
      var totalAdd = parseFloat(newVal* parseFloat(price));
         // $button.closest(".totalprice > i").text(totalAdd) ;   

    } else {
   // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }
  $button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal); 
  $button.closest("ul").siblings(".totalprice").find("i").text(totalAdd) ; 

});

    });
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r4xfqfgw/1/)